# Edit Tooltip in CDE dashboard

Tags: pentaho, dashboard

How Can I edit the default tooltip in CDE dashboard ? If the tooltip of piechart like this:

```
Series: Fuel
Category : D
Value: 0.15
```

I want to change Series, Category, Value to the others title.
Thankyou

Comment: I have answer already, put this function in pre execute function f(){series:[lable:somethingchange]}

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link in pentaho forums: http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?141559-Edit-Tooltip-in-CDE-dashboard

I tried that and it worked.

Copied the original answer from pentaho forums to here which suggested by Mogsdad:

> the labels that show in the tooltip by each value are the labels of the corresponding dimensions.
>
> If you want to show a radically different tooltip, you have to specify the option tooltipFormat.
>
> If you just want to change the labels that show up, then only the labels of the dimensions need to be changed.
>
> Because dimensions can be defined with arbitrary names (even though the default names are well known) there are no fixed CDE properties.
>   The names must be changed in JS code.
>
> Changing the label of default dimensions
>
> Add the following code to the CDE chart component's postFetch handler:
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> function f(data) {
>   // Change the labels of the default dimensions
>   // See http://www.webdetails.pt/charts/jsdoc/symbols/pvc.options.charts.Chart.html#dimensions
>   this.chartDefinition.dimensions = {
>     series:     {label: "Product Family"},
>     category: {label: "Period"},
>     value:      {label: "Sales" }
>   };
>   return data;
> }
> ```
>
> Changing the names and labels of dimensions
>
> It is also possible to change the names of dimensions to match the names of corresponding business concepts:
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> function f(data) {
>    var options = this.chartDefinition;
>    // It is not necessary to explicitly define dimensions
>    // They are created automatically, with appropriate default properties, 
>    // when referring to their names in certain other properties.
>    // But we can define them anyway, if we want to change the default labels.
>    // Default labels are taken from the data source, when possible,
>    // or derived from the dimensions' names.
>    // See http://www.webdetails.pt/charts/jsdo...tml#dimensions
>    this.chartDefinition.dimensions = {
>      productFamily: {label: "Product Family"},
>      period: {label: "Period"},
>      sales:  {label: "Sales" }
>    };
>    // MAP columns in the data source to corresponding dimensions
>    // See http://www.webdetails.pt/charts/jsdo...t.html#readers
>    options.readers = [{names: "productFamily, period, sales"}];
>    // MAP dimensions to the chart's Visual Roles
>    // See http://www.webdetails.pt/charts/jsdo...ml#visualRoles
>    // The following can also be set as CDE properties.
>    // The "series" role receives the data of the "productFamily" dimension
>    // See http://www.webdetails.pt/charts/jsdo...tml#seriesRole
>    options.seriesRole = "productFamily";
>    // The "category" role receives the data of the "period" dimension
>    // See http://www.webdetails.pt/charts/jsdo...l#categoryRole
>    options.categoryRole = "period";
>    // The "value" role receives the data of the "sales" dimension
>    // See http://www.webdetails.pt/charts/jsdo...html#valueRole
>    options.valueRole = "sales";
>    return data;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

to change CDEdashboard tooltip, add this function in to Post Fetch.

```
function f(data) {    
    this.chartDefinition.dimensions = {
        series: {isHidden: true},
        category: {label: "Category"},
        value:      {label: "Value" }
    };   
    return data;
}
```